# Why won't PayPal NVP accept my currency code?

Tags: php, paypal

I want the paypal express checkout page to show show totals in $AUD but it won't accept it.

This works no problem

```
$nvpStr =  "&RETURNURL=$returnURL
            &CANCELURL=$cancelURL
            &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
            &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$total
            &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=$total
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=$name
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=$quantity
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=$price
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=$description
            &NOSHIPPING=1 
            ";
```

But this returns error code [L_LONGMESSAGE1] => Currency is not supported.

```
$nvpStr =  "&RETURNURL=$returnURL
            &CANCELURL=$cancelURL
            &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
            &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$total
            &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=$total
            &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=AUD
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=$name
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=$quantity
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=$price
            &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=$description
            &NOSHIPPING=1 
            ";
```

Infact, it doesn't matter what I select code PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE , EUR, USD , it always returns that error. I've tried Caps and no caps, check for whitespace etc..

Also tried url encoding currency code in per suggestion but same error.

```
$cc = urlencode("AUD");

    $nvpStr =  "&RETURNURL=$returnURL
                &CANCELURL=$cancelURL
                &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
                &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$total
                &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=$total
                &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=$cc
                &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=$name
                &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=$quantity
                &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=$price
                &L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=$description
                &NOSHIPPING=1 
                ";
```

What gives?

Comment: Have you already asked PayPal? Maybe you have the wrong currency format (does it accept another currency?)

Comment: I have tried EUR, UAD, GPB, even USD doesn't work. Emailed paypal tech yesterday but no reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must url encode the currency type.

Such as:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'=>urlencode('GBP')
```

Comment: Damn. Thought that was going to be it but same again.

Comment: @TijuanaKez So all of your other variables are going through except the currency?